# Linux Application Error on Heroku Open Node App

Tags: linux, node.js, heroku

When I heroku open a basic node app, I get a series of errors. This comes after a successful heroku push.
I looked on GitHub and found the same error for a windows user, but I'm on a mac. It was suggested to run the command 
`--no-bin-links` though I do not know what that will do. Help, please.

```
$ heroku logs
2015-11-18T22:00:42.465970+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:00:42.465970+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:01:13.964233+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 95ab50f by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:01:13.964233+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:01:13.898217+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:01:14.302776+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-18T22:01:14.302785+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-18T22:01:15.248283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-11-18T22:01:17.147380+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:17.147400+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:17.147399+00:00 app[web.1]: > shufflebod@0.0.0 start /app
2015-11-18T22:01:17.147400+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-11-18T22:01:17.709403+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-66-generic
2015-11-18T22:01:17.709767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-11-18T22:01:17.710006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.0.0
2015-11-18T22:01:17.710500+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
2015-11-18T22:01:17.710886+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-11-18T22:01:17.711057+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! shufflebod@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2015-11-18T22:01:17.711204+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-11-18T22:01:17.711370+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2015-11-18T22:01:17.711524+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the shufflebod@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2015-11-18T22:01:17.711690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the shufflebod package,
2015-11-18T22:01:17.711879+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-11-18T22:01:17.712210+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-11-18T22:01:17.712025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-11-18T22:01:17.712359+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-11-18T22:01:17.712648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2015-11-18T22:01:17.712503+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls shufflebod
2015-11-18T22:01:17.715348+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:17.715563+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2015-11-18T22:01:17.715707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697334+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697338+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697339+00:00 app[web.1]:         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697340+00:00 app[web.1]:                                       ^
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697341+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697343+00:00 app[web.1]:     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
2015-11-18T22:01:17.697342+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
2015-11-18T22:01:17.704845+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:18.349594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-18T22:01:19.268580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-11-18T22:01:20.934317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:20.934327+00:00 app[web.1]: > shufflebod@0.0.0 start /app
2015-11-18T22:01:20.934328+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-11-18T22:01:20.934329+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:21.402689+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-66-generic
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389182+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389186+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
2015-11-18T22:01:21.403047+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-11-18T22:01:21.403274+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.0.0
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389187+00:00 app[web.1]:         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389188+00:00 app[web.1]:                                       ^
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389220+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389223+00:00 app[web.1]:     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
2015-11-18T22:01:21.403921+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
2015-11-18T22:01:21.389222+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-11-18T22:01:21.398077+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404250+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! shufflebod@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404341+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404490+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404594+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the shufflebod@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404805+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404703+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the shufflebod package,
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-11-18T22:01:21.405100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-11-18T22:01:21.404998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-11-18T22:01:21.405200+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls shufflebod
2015-11-18T22:01:21.405292+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2015-11-18T22:01:21.407531+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-18T22:01:21.407693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2015-11-18T22:01:21.407785+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-11-18T22:01:21.971588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-18T22:01:21.992188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-18T22:01:18.396645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-18T22:01:18.397743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-18T22:01:46.680907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=arcane-scrubland-5339.herokuapp.com request_id=1b2efaee-c58e-4f2f-9c5d-9cac682c21e8 fwd="208.191.152.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-18T22:01:48.353321+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=arcane-scrubland-5339.herokuapp.com request_id=7bbff939-36e5-4566-9556-a00e705dd48f fwd="208.191.152.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-18T22:02:06.643850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=arcane-scrubland-5339.herokuapp.com request_id=eca3d154-2aa1-4c4c-86b7-0a12d7043302 fwd="208.191.152.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-18T22:02:06.931913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=arcane-scrubland-5339.herokuapp.com request_id=fb796d4c-c4ce-4696-a019-8d1e208ad8ef fwd="208.191.152.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-18T22:10:19.380625+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-18T22:10:19.380667+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-18T22:10:19.245516+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 52e6c8e by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:10:19.245516+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by adamcweitzman@gmail.com
2015-11-18T22:10:19.481578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-18T22:10:20.489282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `nodemon bin/www`
2015-11-18T22:10:22.069790+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: nodemon: command not found
2015-11-18T22:10:22.731271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-11-18T22:10:22.755823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-18T22:10:25.421596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=arcane-scrubland-5339.herokuapp.com request_id=fd282f48-9ccb-4e9a-ba08-2db5d503ab3e fwd="208.191.152.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-18T22:10:30.012124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=arcane-scrubland-5339.herokuapp.com request_id=5704bcfe-ad83-4a8a-ae02-b7cc590f1e7b fwd="208.191.152.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured a solution, not sure why it works though...

in my package.json I had `node: nodemon bin/www` when I needed `web: node ./bin/www` I do not know why this is the case, if someone could explain, that would be amazing.